autocomplete bday-day, bday-month or bday-year isn't working
I'm trying to have an autocomplete on my new library
I want to split the birthday into three fields, day, month and year.
So for autocompletion, I've used bday-day, bday-month and bday-year.
But this isn't working.

Code reproduction
Code example

   <input
     matInput
     type="string"
     formControlName="day"
     name="day"
     autocomplete="bday-day"
     max="31"
     inputMode="numeric"
     [placeholder]="placeholders[0]"
   />

Can somebody help me out ?
